# how to make click event when i click next or select page size with "mat-paginator " in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination

I am developing a webpage and i have to show list of items with pagination for an api . show when i select a pagesize or click to next page i have to click a method in ts file . but i don't know how to do it . .

html

```
   <mat-paginator 
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15, 20]"
    [pageSize]="5"
    aria-label="Select page"
    
    ></mat-paginator>
```

ts file

```
  searchData:responsebody[] =[];
 dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
 dataObs$!: Observable<any>;
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.setPagination();
  
  }

  setPagination() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.searchData);
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataObs$ = this.dataSource.connect();
  }


//

nextpageData(pagesize:number,index:number){


}
```

so when i slect page size or click next page i want to call this method "nextpageData(param1,param2)"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mat-paginator` has a `page` event:

> Event emitted when the paginator changes the page size or page index.

```html
<mat-paginator (page)="yourHandler($event)"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: i am new for web developing can you tell how cani get pagesize and index from $event

Comment: <mat-paginator (page)="yourHandler(pageEvent.pageIndex,pageEvent.pageSize)"></mat-paginator>

Comment: @ayeshchanaka `<mat-paginator (page)="yourHandler($event.pageIndex, $event.pageSize)"></mat-paginator>`